Parallel hint in Oracle
I am making many updates on the table which has millions of records, and I tried using parallel hint, but it isn't working and sometimes it is worse than without parallel hint,
  MERGE /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL(4) */ INTO Account a
        USING (
            SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT account) AS countAccount 
            FROM Account  
            WHERE accountStatus = 'Active' 
            GROUP BY id
        ) ba 
        ON (ba.id = a.id) 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET a.countAccount = ba.countAccount;

I have CPU with 4 cores and 16 gb ram.
I got the following after running select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor and I got parallel_max_servers integer 160 from SHOW PARAMETER parallel_max_servers;
Global Information
------------------------------
 Status              :  DONE                
 Instance ID         :  1                   
 Session             :  user (137:53518)     
 SQL ID              :  6y1mrj5498fqd       
 SQL Execution ID    :  16777218            
 Execution Started   :  09/21/2024 18:43:11 
 First Refresh Time  :  09/21/2024 18:43:11 
 Last Refresh Time   :  09/21/2024 18:47:02 
 Duration            :  231s                
 Module/Action       :  SQL Developer/-     
 Service             :  SYS$USERS           
 Program             :  SQL Developer       

Global Stats
==================================================================================================
| Elapsed |   Cpu   |    IO    | Application |  Other   | Buffer | Read  | Read  | Write | Write |
| Time(s) | Time(s) | Waits(s) |  Waits(s)   | Waits(s) |  Gets  | Reqs  | Bytes | Reqs  | Bytes |
==================================================================================================
|     764 |      76 |       34 |        0.08 |      655 |    14M | 17898 |   4GB | 15180 |   2GB |
==================================================================================================

Parallel Execution Details (DOP=4 , Servers Allocated=8)
==================================================================================================================================================
|      Name      | Type  | Server# | Elapsed |   Cpu   |    IO    | Application |  Other   | Buffer | Read | Read  | Write | Write | Wait Events |
|                |       |         | Time(s) | Time(s) | Waits(s) |  Waits(s)   | Waits(s) |  Gets  | Reqs | Bytes | Reqs  | Bytes | (sample #)  |
==================================================================================================================================================
| PX Coordinator | QC    |         |    0.09 |    0.00 |          |        0.08 |     0.01 |     19 |      |     . |       |     . |             |
| p000           | Set 1 |       1 |     192 |      14 |     0.14 |             |      178 |     4M |  662 | 631MB |       |     . |             |
| p001           | Set 1 |       2 |     169 |      13 |     0.15 |             |      156 |     4M |  653 | 624MB |       |     . |             |
| p002           | Set 1 |       3 |     168 |      13 |     0.14 |             |      155 |     4M |  710 | 679MB |       |     . |             |
| p003           | Set 1 |       4 |     180 |      15 |     0.15 |             |      166 |     4M |  693 | 652MB |       |     . |             |
| p004           | Set 2 |       1 |      14 |    5.38 |     8.44 |             |          |        | 3792 | 444MB |  3792 | 444MB |             |
| p005           | Set 2 |       2 |      13 |    5.49 |     7.96 |             |          |        | 3811 | 447MB |  3811 | 447MB |             |
| p006           | Set 2 |       3 |      14 |    5.21 |     8.30 |             |          |        | 3782 | 443MB |  3782 | 443MB |             |
| p007           | Set 2 |       4 |      14 |    5.41 |     8.49 |             |          |        | 3795 | 445MB |  3795 | 445MB |             |
==================================================================================================================================================

SQL Plan Monitoring Details (Plan Hash Value=2917601746)
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
| Id |                Operation                |              Name              |  Rows   | Cost  |   Time    | Start  | Execs |   Rows   | Read  | Read  | Write | Write |  Mem  | Temp  | Activity | Activity Detail |
|    |                                         |                                | (Estim) |       | Active(s) | Active |       | (Actual) | Reqs  | Bytes | Reqs  | Bytes | (Max) | (Max) |   (%)    |   (# samples)   |
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================
|  0 | MERGE STATEMENT                         |                                |         |       |         1 |   +231 |     9 |        8 |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  1 |   PX COORDINATOR                        |                                |         |       |         1 |   +231 |     9 |        8 |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  2 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                  | :TQ10005                       |     13M | 27044 |         1 |   +231 |     4 |        8 |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  3 |     MERGE                               | ACCOUNT                        |         |       |       218 |    +14 |     4 |        4 |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  4 |      PX RECEIVE                         |                                |     13M | 27044 |       218 |    +14 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  5 |       PX SEND (ROWID RANDOM)            | :TQ10004                       |     13M | 27044 |       218 |    +14 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  6 |        VIEW                             |                                |         |       |       218 |    +14 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  7 |         HASH JOIN BUFFERED              |                                |     13M | 27044 |       230 |     +2 |     4 |      13M | 15180 |   2GB | 15180 |   2GB |   49M |    2G |          |                 |
|  8 |          PX RECEIVE                     |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
|  9 |           PX SEND HASH                  | :TQ10002                       |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 10 |            VIEW                         |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 11 |             SORT GROUP BY               |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |   26M |       |          |                 |
| 12 |              PX RECEIVE                 |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 13 |               PX SEND HASH              | :TQ10001                       |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 14 |                SORT GROUP BY            |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |   28M |       |          |                 |
| 15 |                 VIEW                    | VW_DAG_1                       |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 16 |                  SORT GROUP BY          |                                |    366K | 14469 |         2 |     +1 |     4 |     366K |       |       |       |       |   29M |       |          |                 |
| 17 |                   PX RECEIVE            |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     731K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 18 |                    PX SEND HASH         | :TQ10000                       |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     731K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 19 |                     SORT GROUP BY       |                                |    366K | 14469 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     731K |       |       |       |       |  319K |       |          |                 |
| 20 |                      PX BLOCK ITERATOR  |                                |    672K | 12525 |         1 |     +2 |     4 |     732K |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 21 |                       TABLE ACCESS FULL | ACCOUNT                        |    672K | 12525 |         2 |     +1 |    55 |     732K |  1359 |   1GB |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 22 |          PX RECEIVE                     |                                |     13M | 12566 |        13 |     +2 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 23 |           PX SEND HASH                  | :TQ10003                       |     13M | 12566 |        13 |     +2 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 24 |            PX BLOCK ITERATOR            |                                |     13M | 12566 |        13 |     +2 |     4 |      13M |       |       |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
| 25 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL           | ACCOUNT                        |     13M | 12566 |        13 |     +2 |    55 |      13M |  1359 |   1GB |       |       |       |       |          |                 |
========================================================================================================================================================================================================================


The SQL statement and explain plan imply Oracle correctly requests parallelism. But does the database adequately allocate and use the parallel servers, and where is the wait time? Generate a SQL Monitor Report to capture some of that information. Find the SQL_ID of the statement, possibly through GV$SQL, and run this command and edit the results into the question: select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your SQL_ID', type => 'text') from dual; Check for bad parameters, like a low PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS, other sessions consuming parallel servers, and insufficient hardware I/O.

I added the result

That report implies Oracle software is performing well and getting sufficient parallelism, but still only reading and writing 27 MB/s. (Although the "Activity" columns are empty, maybe because the data aged out. Try re-runing the merge and regenerating the report to capture that data.) Maybe this is a hardware limitation. Try reading and writing simple, but large amounts of data, to find the maximum bytes per second. Run this query to check for historical system I/O performance: select * from dba_hist_sysmetric_history where metric_name = 'I/O Megabytes per Second' order by value desc;

I got 172.58655126498 as value

You are getting PDML - it's taking forever because you are updating 100% of the rows in your table, which is a very expensive thing to do. In your particular case, you are actually deriving an aggregate value from other rows and storing it in each row, which violates the basic rules of normalization. What are you to do when a new row is added? Do the same heavy update all over again? It's not a maintainable architecture. Save aggregation like that for queries; don't try to store them in tables, especially not in rows from the very table being aggregated.

If you did insist on doing this, you'd be far better of recreating the segment with a create table as select... and swapping names, or even truncating and re-inserting back from a CTAS-generated worktable, than you are doing an update of every row in your table.

I am making etl and I have many updates so if I make create table I need to make so many and I need to join them where previous updates will be needed in new ones

You will want to rearchitect your process - avoid mass updates. It is far better to create work tables. Direct path loads are far more efficient than updates. It is even better to use CTE (WITH clauses,), within reason to avoid having to write those intermediate worksets to permanent tablespaces.

@AliKhalil Given your data, operation, and maximum I/O performance, the performance you're getting for this MERGE statement isn't actually that bad. Try bumping up the degree of parallelism to 8 or 16. More parallelism is almost always faster, although it can be an inefficient use of resources and may be unfair to other operations. There might be other issues going on, but we'd really need to see the wait operations to dig deeper. Paul's suggestions about DDL could certainly improve performance, but I understand it's not always possible to re-architect the entire process.

Your code will not update an id if the state changes from having one-or-more accounts that are active to having zero accounts that are active.


If possible, rearchitect your application so that you are not storing an aggregated value in the table. Instead, derive the value as needed when you SELECT the data.

An alternative optimisation is to not update all the rows, instead only update the rows that have changed:
MERGE /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL(4) */ INTO Account a
USING (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
           CASE accountStatus
           WHEN 'Active'
           THEN account
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS countAccount
  FROM   Account  
) ba 
ON (    a.ROWID         =  ba.ROWID
    AND a.countAccount  != ba.countAccount
    AND ba.countAccount >  0 -- Your code implicitly checks this.
                             -- I am not sure it is desired behaviour.
) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE
  SET a.countAccount = ba.countAccount;


Another possible solution may be to put a trigger on the table that recalculates the countAccount value when a row is INSERTed or DELETEd or if an UPDATE modifies either the id, account or accountStatus columns of a row and only modify the rows with the same id value as the triggering row. This may need to be a compound trigger if you are making lots of modifications in a single query.


